# Reactjs component with changing views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluxible

I m actually developping an application using Fluxible and Reactjs.

I need to create inside of this app (already using a router) dynamic subroutes inside of a parent component.

In fact, my component is, globally a planning manager. We can see daily, weekly, monthly etc... tasks.

It means that I have multiple components that can be replaced by each other inside of a parent component which can be .

So I was wondering if we can use something like an "inside component  router". I mean this router should work only inside of the concerned component, like changing only the inside components of the parent component Planning.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for react router: https://github.com/rackt/react-router.

Comment: It doesn't have to, you can leave out the path attr. That being said there are almost no scenarios where that's a good idea. URLs are very powerful and you should use them everywhere.

Comment: I can use this router inside of multiple parent components ? Or it's is one router per applications